# How to combine batch file and expect script in cygwin?

Tags: bash, cmd, cygwin, expect

i have an application on windows that requires user name and password to start, but i don't want user to enter the user/password, so i created a script to interact with CMD interface to enter the password, using cygwin on windows 8.1, but i can't find expect command on the Cygwin, and i would like to ask also if my script has any issue.
below is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
sh C:\Users\Osama.Barakat\Desktop\batchfile.bat
expect "Enter the password for administrator:"
send "Pa$$w0rd"
interact
```

Answer (score 0):

I identified two issues in your question:

1. How to perform batch files in cygwin/bash?
2. How to get expect installed/running in cygwin/bash?

**1. How to perform batch files in cygwin/bash?**

In your sample code, I found

```
---8<---
sh C:\Users\Osama.Barakat\Desktop\batchfile.bat
--->8---
```

IMHO, this is a mistake. I believe that `bash` will try to execute anything as script regardless of the script file extension. But if `batchfile.bat` is really a batch file then it should be called with the correct interpreter (i.e. `cmd.exe`) instead.

I tried it to see if there is any issue in the cygwin `bash` but it worked. My sample batch file `test-expect.bat`:

```
@echo off
rem output
echo Hello %USERNAME%
rem input
set /p INPUT= Enter input: 
rem output
echo Input: %INPUT%
```

...tested in `bash` on cygwin:

```
$ cmd /c test-expect.bat 
Hello Scheff
Enter input: Hello cmd
Input: Hello cmd

$
```

OK, done.

**2. How to get expect installed/running in cygwin/bash?**

To install `expect` on cygwin I googled a little bit and found [Installation of Cygwin, expect and Ssh](https://amsathishkumar.wordpress.com/installation-of-cygwin-expect-and-ssh/). Then, I started the cygwin-setup `setup-x86.exe` and tried something else:

On the "Select Packages" page, I set `View` to `Full` and `Search` to `expect`. I got a list of four entries only where the first was: "expect: Tool for automating interactive applications" (Category: Tcl). I choosed this for installation and had to confirm another package as dependency.

After installation, I tried this in an interactive bash:

```
$ which expect
/usr/bin/expect

$
```

OK - looks quite good.

**Combining CMD.EXE and expect**

To put all together, I wrote another test script `test-expect.exp`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn cmd /c test-expect.bat
expect "Enter input: "
send "Hello expect\r"
interact
```

Tested in bash on cygwin:

```
$ ./test-expect.exp
spawn cmd /c test-expect.bat
Hello Scheff
Enter input: Hello expect
Input: Hello expect

$
```

Well, it seems to work.